# Offline database solution for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's task: We have an sql server database. which is hosted at our server. What we need to do is: we need to create a non-techy-users interface (basically insert/edit forms) and let these non-techy-users to install this database locally, since they are located in the areas without internet connection. Then when they're done using the database we get the data from them and inster it in our database.

The biggest concern is that it is not trivial for non-it people to install sql server. Can you please advise me what solution should I choose? Simple Access should work fine, but i really do not want to mess with it and have data conversion back and forth between engines.

Comment: If I were confronted with the same issue to solve, I'd use SQLite, a small-footprint easy-to-install relational database which could be used as an offline datastore that could be synched with the server periodically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sync Framework for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608): your application uses a lite weight, embedded SQL Server CE (no installation, just a couple of DLLs deployed along with your app) and the sync framework manages the synchronization with the 'mother ship' SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, why do they need their own installation? Can't you create a new database on your existing instance?

If you're looking for an easy way to create insert/edit forms on your database, have you considered looking at Microsoft's new [LightSwitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch) product (currently in Beta) or Microsoft's [Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata)?